# Summing multiple rows having duplicate columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,1,3,4,2], 'c':['dd','ee','dd','as','ae','ee'], 'count':[5,9,1,6,8,3]})`

```
   a   c  count
0  1  dd      5
1  2  ee      9
2  1  dd      1
3  3  as      6
4  4  ae      8
5  2  ee      3
```

As you can see there  are duplicates in column 'a' `1 and 2` are repeated multiple times.

i want to sum the count of such in pandas  like in sql we do groupby.

my final df should look like this

```
   a   c  count
0  1  dd      6
1  2  ee      12
2  3  as      6
3  4  ae      8
```

i tried by using 
`df = df.groupby('a')` but it is returning me

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns `a` and `c` with aggregating [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['a','c'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
print (df)
   a   c  count
0  1  dd      6
1  2  ee     12
2  3  as      6
3  4  ae      8
```

But if need groupby only column `a`, then is necessary [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) all columns which need in output - e.g. column `c` is aggregate by `first` and `count` by `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby('a').agg({'c':'first', 'count':'sum'}).reset_index()
print (df)
   a   c  count
0  1  dd      6
1  2  ee     12
2  3  as      6
3  4  ae      8
```

Answer (score 6):

You almost had it

```
df.groupby(['a', 'c']).sum().reset_index()
```

yields

```
   a   c  count
0  1  dd      6
1  2  ee     12
2  3  as      6
3  4  ae      8
```